# mysql keeps restarting: docker-compose bitnami/mysql5.7

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose, bitnami, mysql-5.7

When I run `docker-compose up -d`, phpmyadmin starts, mysql starts and stops and continues restarting.

Can someone tell me what the problem is? It seemed like when I manually specified the password in quotes it worked, but now I can't seem to make any progress

Do you get mysql restarting when you run this? If so, how can you tell what the problem is?

I'm on a new install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Thanks in advance

```
root@project:/home/user/project# cat .env
NODE_ENV=production
NODE_PORT=88
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_HOST=127.0.0.1
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_DB=testdb
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Pass(word123)
ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=no
PHPMYADMIN_HTTP_PORT=4324
```

```
root@project:/home/user/project#
root@project:/home/user/project# cat docker-compose.yml
---
version: "3.4"
services:
  db:
    image: "bitnami/mysql:5.7"
    user: root
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    networks:
      - db
    volumes:
      - projectvolume:/bitnami/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD:
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${PHPMYADMIN_HTTP_PORT}:80"
    networks:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: "${MYSQL_PORT}"
networks:
  db:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  projectvolume:
```

```
root@project:/home/user/project#
root@project:/home/user/project# docker-compose config
networks:
  db:
    driver: bridge
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    environment:
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Pass(word123)
    image: bitnami/mysql:5.7
    networks:
      db: null
    ports:
    - published: 3306
      target: 3306
    restart: always
    user: root
    volumes:
    - projectvolume:/bitnami/mysql:rw
  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
    - db
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: '3306'
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    networks:
      db: null
    ports:
    - published: 5050
      target: 80
    restart: always
version: '3.4'
volumes:
  projectvolume: {}

root@project:/home/user/project#
```

Here is docker ps showing mysql restarting

```
root@project:/home/user/project# docker-compose up -d
Creating network "project_db" with driver "bridge"
Creating db ... 
Creating db ... done
Creating phpmyadmin ... 
Creating phpmyadmin ... done
root@project:/home/user/project# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                    NAMES
da4357bf9eb4        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   9 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds            0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp     phpmyadmin
e791552657f7        bitnami/mysql:5.7       "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   10 seconds ago      Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   db
root@project:/home/user/project# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
da4357bf9eb4        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   10 seconds ago      Up 8 seconds        0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp     phpmyadmin
e791552657f7        bitnami/mysql:5.7       "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   11 seconds ago      Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   db
root@project:/home/user/project# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                  NAMES
da4357bf9eb4        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   11 seconds ago      Up 9 seconds                   0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp   phpmyadmin
e791552657f7        bitnami/mysql:5.7       "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   12 seconds ago      Restarting (11) 1 second ago                          db
root@project:/home/user/project# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                    NAMES
da4357bf9eb4        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   13 seconds ago      Up 11 seconds           0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp     phpmyadmin
e791552657f7        bitnami/mysql:5.7       "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   14 seconds ago      Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   db
root@project:/home/user/project# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
da4357bf9eb4        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   14 seconds ago      Up 12 seconds       0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp     phpmyadmin
e791552657f7        bitnami/mysql:5.7       "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   15 seconds ago      Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   db
root@project:/home/user/project# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                                   PORTS                  NAMES
da4357bf9eb4        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   15 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds                            0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp   phpmyadmin
e791552657f7        bitnami/mysql:5.7       "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   16 seconds ago      Restarting (11) Less than a second ago                          db
root@project:/home/user/project# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                  NAMES
da4357bf9eb4        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   16 seconds ago      Up 14 seconds                  0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp   phpmyadmin
e791552657f7        bitnami/mysql:5.7       "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   17 seconds ago      Restarting (11) 1 second ago                          db
da4357bf9eb4        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   17 seconds ago      Up 15 seconds           0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp     phpmyadmin
root@project:/home/user/project# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                    NAMES
e791552657f7        bitnami/mysql:5.7       "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   18 seconds ago      Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   db
root@project:/home/user/project# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
da4357bf9eb4        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   18 seconds ago      Up 15 seconds       0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp     phpmyadmin
e791552657f7        bitnami/mysql:5.7       "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   19 seconds ago      Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   db
root@project:/home/user/project# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
da4357bf9eb4        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   19 seconds ago      Up 16 seconds       0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp     phpmyadmin
e791552657f7        bitnami/mysql:5.7       "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   20 seconds ago      Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   db
root@project:/home/user/project# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                                   PORTS                  NAMES
da4357bf9eb4        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   20 seconds ago      Up 17 seconds                            0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp   phpmyadmin
e791552657f7        bitnami/mysql:5.7       "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   21 seconds ago      Restarting (11) Less than a second ago                          db
root@project:/home/user/project#
```

Here's the docker-compose output:

```
root@project:/home/user/project# docker-compose up
Creating network "project_db" with driver "bridge"
Creating db ... 
Creating db ... done
Creating phpmyadmin ... 
Creating phpmyadmin ... done
Attaching to db, phpmyadmin
phpmyadmin    | phpMyAdmin not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 Welcome to the Bitnami mysql container
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql/issues
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 
db            | mysql 07:20:43.49 INFO  ==> ** Starting MySQL setup **
db            | mysql 07:20:43.58 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars
db            | mysql 07:20:43.69 INFO  ==> Initializing mysql database
db            | mysql 07:20:43.72 INFO  ==> Using persisted data
db            | mysql 07:20:43.75 INFO  ==> Running mysql_upgrade
db            | mysql 07:20:43.76 INFO  ==> Starting mysql in background
db            | mysql 07:20:44.80 INFO  ==> Stopping mysql
phpmyadmin    | Complete! phpMyAdmin has been successfully copied to /var/www/html
phpmyadmin    | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.29.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
phpmyadmin    | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.29.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
phpmyadmin    | [Wed Dec 18 07:20:45.128237 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.2.25 configured -- resuming normal operations
phpmyadmin    | [Wed Dec 18 07:20:45.128321 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'

db exited with code 11
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 Welcome to the Bitnami mysql container
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql/issues
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 
db            | mysql 07:20:43.49 INFO  ==> ** Starting MySQL setup **
db            | mysql 07:20:43.58 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars
db            | mysql 07:20:43.69 INFO  ==> Initializing mysql database
db            | mysql 07:20:43.72 INFO  ==> Using persisted data
db            | mysql 07:20:43.75 INFO  ==> Running mysql_upgrade
db            | mysql 07:20:43.76 INFO  ==> Starting mysql in background
db            | mysql 07:20:44.80 INFO  ==> Stopping mysql
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | mysql 07:20:48.31 
db            | mysql 07:20:48.31 Welcome to the Bitnami mysql container
db            | mysql 07:20:48.31 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql
db            | mysql 07:20:48.31 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql/issues
db            | mysql 07:20:48.31 Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
db            | mysql 07:20:48.32 
db            | mysql 07:20:48.32 INFO  ==> ** Starting MySQL setup **
db            | mysql 07:20:48.38 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars
db            | mysql 07:20:48.39 INFO  ==> Initializing mysql database
db            | mysql 07:20:48.42 INFO  ==> Using persisted data
db            | mysql 07:20:48.43 INFO  ==> Running mysql_upgrade
db            | mysql 07:20:48.43 INFO  ==> Starting mysql in background
db            | mysql 07:20:49.46 INFO  ==> Stopping mysql
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | mysql 07:20:51.93 
db            | mysql 07:20:51.93 Welcome to the Bitnami mysql container
db            | mysql 07:20:51.94 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql
db            | mysql 07:20:51.94 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql/issues
db            | mysql 07:20:51.94 Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
db            | mysql 07:20:51.94 
db            | mysql 07:20:51.94 INFO  ==> ** Starting MySQL setup **
db            | mysql 07:20:52.02 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars
db            | mysql 07:20:52.03 INFO  ==> Initializing mysql database
db            | mysql 07:20:52.05 INFO  ==> Using persisted data
db            | mysql 07:20:52.07 INFO  ==> Running mysql_upgrade
db            | mysql 07:20:52.07 INFO  ==> Starting mysql in background


db            | mysql 07:20:53.10 INFO  ==> Stopping mysql
db exited with code 11
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 Welcome to the Bitnami mysql container
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql/issues
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
db            | mysql 07:20:43.48 
db            | mysql 07:20:43.49 INFO  ==> ** Starting MySQL setup **
db            | mysql 07:20:43.58 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars
db            | mysql 07:20:43.69 INFO  ==> Initializing mysql database
db            | mysql 07:20:43.72 INFO  ==> Using persisted data
db            | mysql 07:20:43.75 INFO  ==> Running mysql_upgrade
db            | mysql 07:20:43.76 INFO  ==> Starting mysql in background
db            | mysql 07:20:44.80 INFO  ==> Stopping mysql
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | mysql 07:20:48.31 
db            | mysql 07:20:48.31 Welcome to the Bitnami mysql container
db            | mysql 07:20:48.31 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql
db            | mysql 07:20:48.31 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql/issues
db            | mysql 07:20:48.31 Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
db            | mysql 07:20:48.32 
db            | mysql 07:20:48.32 INFO  ==> ** Starting MySQL setup **
db            | mysql 07:20:48.38 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars
db            | mysql 07:20:48.39 INFO  ==> Initializing mysql database
db            | mysql 07:20:48.42 INFO  ==> Using persisted data
db            | mysql 07:20:48.43 INFO  ==> Running mysql_upgrade
db            | mysql 07:20:48.43 INFO  ==> Starting mysql in background
db            | mysql 07:20:49.46 INFO  ==> Stopping mysql
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | mysql 07:20:51.93 
db            | mysql 07:20:51.93 Welcome to the Bitnami mysql container
db            | mysql 07:20:51.94 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql
db            | mysql 07:20:51.94 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql/issues
db            | mysql 07:20:51.94 Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
db            | mysql 07:20:51.94 
db            | mysql 07:20:51.94 INFO  ==> ** Starting MySQL setup **
db            | mysql 07:20:52.02 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars
db            | mysql 07:20:52.03 INFO  ==> Initializing mysql database
db            | mysql 07:20:52.05 INFO  ==> Using persisted data
db            | mysql 07:20:52.07 INFO  ==> Running mysql_upgrade
db            | mysql 07:20:52.07 INFO  ==> Starting mysql in background
db            | mysql 07:20:53.10 INFO  ==> Stopping mysql
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | mysql 07:20:55.75 
db            | mysql 07:20:55.75 Welcome to the Bitnami mysql container
db            | mysql 07:20:55.75 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql
db            | mysql 07:20:55.76 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql/issues
db            | mysql 07:20:55.76 Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
db            | mysql 07:20:55.76 
db            | mysql 07:20:55.76 INFO  ==> ** Starting MySQL setup **
db            | mysql 07:20:55.83 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars
db            | mysql 07:20:55.84 INFO  ==> Initializing mysql database
db            | mysql 07:20:55.86 INFO  ==> Using persisted data
db            | mysql 07:20:55.87 INFO  ==> Running mysql_upgrade
db            | mysql 07:20:55.88 INFO  ==> Starting mysql in background
db            | mysql 07:20:56.90 INFO  ==> Stopping mysql
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 500: DB_FLAVOR: unbound variable
db            | /libmysql.sh: line 513: : bad substitution
db            | mysql 07:21:01.00 
db            | mysql 07:21:01.00 Welcome to the Bitnami mysql container
db            | mysql 07:21:01.00 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql
db            | mysql 07:21:01.00 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql/issues
db            | mysql 07:21:01.01 Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
db            | mysql 07:21:01.01 
db            | mysql 07:21:01.01 INFO  ==> ** Starting MySQL setup **
db            | mysql 07:21:01.08 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars
db            | mysql 07:21:01.09 INFO  ==> Initializing mysql database
db            | mysql 07:21:01.11 INFO  ==> Using persisted data
db            | mysql 07:21:01.13 INFO  ==> Running mysql_upgrade
db            | mysql 07:21:01.14 INFO  ==> Starting mysql in background
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping phpmyadmin ... done
Stopping db         ... done
root@project:/home/user/project#
```

## UPDATE:

So this is really confusing me: If I replace the volume `projectvolume` with a new volume, mysql behaves normally.

I believe when I changed the password in the .env file it somehow screwed things up. Setting the password back to its original value did not resolve the problem.

Now, I thought perhaps this was a UID/GID kind of problem, I've double checked and the file permissions and UID/GID have not changed and are correct to the best of my knowledge. The original volume that was working was created by the container when I ran `docker-compose up` the first time, I created a database and loaded it with data through phpmyadmin without trouble. Everything was working great.

So why is it that changing the password screws things up? I want to be able to use this docker-compose file for a production server, but with it being so temper-mental about changing things I'm not so sure. I've read online and even talked to co-workers who are familiar with docker and docker-compose, as long as the UID/GID are correction there shouldn't be a problem. So is this a problem with the bitnami/mysql5.7 container itself?

I'd still like to learn how to resolve this so that I can use this for production deploy. I'm hoping to launch the project by the weekend and I'm just at a loss as to what to do about this. Thanks again for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a similar question in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql/issues/84), Bitnami team released a new image version with a fix.
Was it a valid solution for you?